# Как поправить данный алгоритм?

Tags: c#

у меня есть задача: написать логику работы led.
По коду может будет понятно, но я хочу дополнить все равно.
Я могу вызвать команду **SetStateOn**, передав такие аргументы: `OutputLedColorType? Color, OutputLedAlternatingState Alternating, TimeSpan? Duration`

Если Color null, то берется OutputLedColorType.Default, если Duration null, то берется большой TimeSpan.
Если вызвать SetStateOn без аргументов, то State должен просто поменяться один раз. Если указан Alternating, то идет немного другая логика - там вызываются разные цвета и получается чередование.

У меня такая проблема: вызываю SetStateOn, State меняется и все хорошо, но если еще раз вызвать SetStateOn с аргументом Duration = TimeSpan... , то State примет обратное значение, что неверно, ведь мы включаем включенное, выключать нельзя.
Проблема, наверное, в следующем месте:

```
if ( State != _primaryColor )
{
       State = _primaryColor;
       _timer.Change( _repeatCount, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan );
}
else
      State = OutputLedColorType.None;
```

Если мы один раз поменяли State, то повторное выполнение метода, заменит State на None..
Вообще этот кусок кода был написан для следующей цели: мы можем вызвать SetStateOn с Duration = 10 seconds.. После 10 секунд, метод должен вернуть исходное значение, собственно поэтому State и меняется на None. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я могу с этим сделать? Я как-то не могу понять

Вот мой код:

```
public class LedStateTimedProcessor
    : Disposable
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly object _sync = new();

    private OutputLedColorType _color;

    public LedStateTimedProcessor( OutputLedColorType color )
    {
        _color = color;
        _timer = new Timer( OnTimer );
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if ( disposing )
            _timer.Dispose();

        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    public OutputLedColorType State
    {
        get => _color;
        private set
        {
            if ( _color == value )
                return;

            _color = value;
            StateChanged?.Invoke( _color );
        }
    }

    public Action<OutputLedColorType> StateChanged { get; set; }

    private TimeSpan _cycles;
    private TimeSpan _repeatCount;
    private TimeSpan _durationPrimary;
    private TimeSpan _durationAlternating;
    private OutputLedColorType _primaryColor;
    private OutputLedColorType _alternatingColor;
    private bool _isAlternating;

    public void SetStateOn( OutputLedOnArguments arguments )
    {
        lock ( _sync )
        {
            _cycles = TimeSpan.Zero;
            _repeatCount = arguments.Duration ?? TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            _primaryColor = arguments.Color ?? OutputLedColorType.Default;

            _isAlternating = arguments.Alternating.IsNotNull();

            if ( _isAlternating )
            {
                _durationAlternating = arguments.Alternating.DurationAlternating;
                _durationPrimary = arguments.Alternating.DurationPrimary;
                _alternatingColor = arguments.Alternating.Color;
            }

            OnTimer( null );
        }
    }

    public void SetStateOff( OutputLedOffArguments arguments )
    {
        var stateOld = State;

        lock ( _sync )
        {
            State = OutputLedColorType.None;
            _cycles += arguments.Duration ?? Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
            _timer.Change( arguments.Duration ?? Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan );
        }
        
        if ( stateOld != State )
            StateChanged?.Invoke( State );
    }

    private void OnTimer( object state )
    {
        var stateOld = State;

        lock ( _sync )
            if ( _isAlternating )
            {
                if ( State != _primaryColor )
                {
                    State = _primaryColor;
                    _timer.Change( _durationPrimary, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan );
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( _cycles >= _repeatCount )
                    {
                        _timer.Change( Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan );

                        return;
                    }

                    State = _alternatingColor;
                    _timer.Change( _durationAlternating, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan );

                    _cycles += _durationPrimary + _durationAlternating;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ( _repeatCount == TimeSpan.MaxValue )
                {
                    State = _primaryColor;
                    _timer.Change( Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan );
                }

                else
                {
                    if ( State != _primaryColor )
                    {
                        State = _primaryColor;
                        _timer.Change( _repeatCount, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan );
                    }
                    else
                        State = OutputLedColorType.None;
                }
            }

        if ( stateOld != State )
            StateChanged?.Invoke( State );
    }
}
```

Comment: сложно понять проблему, но я вижу много if'ов и состояния, потому просто посоветую рассмотреть вариант как сюда прикрутить машину состояний. Чтобы был детерменированный конечный набор состояний вашей лампочки и правила перезода от одного состояния в другое.

Comment: ну проблема ясна - представьте, что State = On. Мы вызываем команду еще раз и попадаем в проверку: if ( State != _primaryColor ), которую мы проваливаем, спускаемся ниже и меняем на None

Comment: я просто не понимаю, как это можно исправить

Comment: @tym32167 я для тестов сделал вот такой проект: https://gist.github.com/INTERNALINTERFERENCE/22a29c142908a87fd1a5756c3f17ad9d
может поможет

Comment: А зачем здесь вообще таймер и какой именно таймер используется? Что за тип приложения? Как это тестируете?

Comment: Используется таймер из System.Threading. Я знаю, что можно попробовать через Task.Delay, но мне хочется использовать именно таймер. Тестовое приложение, которое я выше скинул - консольное, его можно просто запустить. А так.. ну у меня есть контроллер, в который я код свой залил и тестирую. При отправке команды SetStateOn, лампочка загорается, но при повторной отправке SetStateOn с Duration, гаснет.. Проблема, наверное, в том месте, где я добавлял логику изменения State через какое-то время - SetStateOn с Duration = 10 включит лампочку, которая погаснет только через 10 секунд